# Splitting a sentence below a specific "space" character with regex in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have been trying to solve a problem for splitting a sentence down to a meaningful set of words under specific length.

```
string1 = "Alice is in wonderland"
string2 = "Bob is playing games on his computer"
```

I want to have a regex that matches the representative words that match the condition of being lower than 20 characters.

```
new_string1 = "Alice is in"
new_string2 = "Bob is playing games"
```

Is this possible to do it with Regex?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good usecase of regular expression. Although, the [`textwrap.shorten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.shorten) method achieves exactly that.

```
import textwrap

string1 = "Alice is in wonderland"
string2 = "Bob is playing games on his computer"

new_string1 = textwrap.shorten(string1, 20, placeholder="")
new_string2 = textwrap.shorten(string2, 20, placeholder="")

print(new_string1) # Alice is in
print(new_string2) # Bob is playing games
```

The only downside of `textwrap.shorten` is that it collapses spaces. In the event you do not want that to happen, you can implement your own method.

```
def shorten(s, max_chars):
    # Special case is the string is shorter than the number of required chars
    if len(s) <= max_chars:
        return s.rstrip()

    stop = 0
    for i in range(max_chars + 1):
        # Always keep the location of the last space behind the pointer
        if s[i].isspace():
            stop = i

    # Get rid of possible extra space added on the tail of the string
    return s[:stop].rstrip()

string1 = "Alice is in wonderland"
string2 = "Bob is playing games on his computer"

new_string1 = shorten(string1, 20)
new_string2 = shorten(string2, 20)

print(new_string1) # Alice is in
print(new_string2) # Bob is playing games
```

Comment: Someone commented as string1[:32].rsplit(None, 1)[0]. I prefer this to your answer, as I have already a function to do this. but I was trying to achieve the shortest possible way (if possible with regex).

Comment: @Sojimanatsu `string1[:20].rsplit(None, 1)[0]` will not work. Think of the cases where the slice ends exactly at the of a word, it will then chop the last word even though it should be included. This actually exactly happens for your string2 (with 20 characters)

Regarding regex, this is really not the right tool for that. You'd be using a hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: But then I can control this situation with if statement cant I? I mean if I say 
if len(string) > 20 do this if not just process it as it is. What is wrong with this? @Olivier Melançon

Comment: @Sojimanatsu First, the regex I can think of would be pretty unreadable, and so hard to maintain. Furthermore, regex are generally not good at anything which relate to counting and keeping track of an arbitrary amount of paste characters. And finally... there is an easier way, use the easier way.

You can read more here if you wish: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions